# Describe $x/(x+1) < 0$ with an interval

Tags: inequality, fake-proofs

I am doing this exercise in a Calculus textbook. Describe all solutions $\frac{x}{x+1} < 0$ as an interval. I think I did successfully and got the solution $x \in (-1,0)$ by considering signs of $x$ and $x+1$. But then I tried this alternative approach.

$$\frac{x}{x+1} < 0$$

Doing long division gives

$$1-\frac{1}{x+1}< 0$$

And so

$$\frac{1}{x+1} > 1$$

Since LHS is greater than $1$, I take absolute value.

$$|\frac{1}{x+1}| > 1$$

Now I take the reciprocal

$$|x+1| < 1 $$

And so $x \in (-2,0)$

So, where is the mistake?.

Comment: not all reals which satisfy $ \frac{1}{|x+1|}>1$ satify  $ \frac{1}{x+1}>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to arrive to the exact solution set at the end, you want a chain of equivalences such as
$$\frac{x}{x+1}<0 \iff 1- \frac1{x+1}<0 \iff \cdots\iff x\in (-1,0).$$

In that case you can be sure that the values of $x$ that verify the original inequality are those in $(-1,0)$ and not any other.

So you should check that you can revert every step. You would then find out that while
$$\frac1{x+1}>1 \implies \left|\frac1{x+1} \right|>1$$
(because $1>0$), it is not true that 
$$\color{red}{\left|\frac1{x+1} \right|>1 \implies \frac1{x+1}>1} $$
(for instance $-\tfrac32$ satisfies the left inequality but not the right inequality.

So, since you have several equivalences but one step only works to the right you have only proved that
$$\frac{x}{x+1}<0 \implies x\in (-2,0),$$
which is true, since you actually now that the solution is $x\in (-1,0)\subset (-2,0)$.

Comment: Oh my our answers are so similar. But tell me are they called biconditinoal or equivalences

Comment: Hey, I think both are ok. I would use 'biconditional' for the symbol $\iff$ and 'equivalence' for an expression like $p\iff q$, but I don't think that it would be such a big deal.

Comment: Maybe 'double implication' would be fine both for the symbol and the expression, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks! I am new in logic, Ill try to read more. liked your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1}{|1+x|}>1$$

Does not imply:

$$\frac{1}{1+x}>1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note as an example $x > 1 \implies |x| > 1$ but $|x| > 1$ does not imply $x > 1$! We need biconditionals here for moving from one step to other. Here your proof in wrong because

$$\frac{1}{x+1} > 1 \iff \frac{1}{|x+1|} > 1$$

is **false**, because first part of biconditional is satisfied: $\frac{1}{x+1} > 1 \implies \frac{1}{|x+1|} > 1$ but the other part of biconditional $\frac{1}{|x+1|} > 1 \implies\frac{1}{x+1} > 1 $ is not.

Take for example, $x = -1.5$. Then $\frac{1}{|x+1|} = 2$ but $\frac{1}{x+1} = -2$.

Comment: We have even used the same (obvious, BTW) counterexample. LOL

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\frac{x}{x+1}<0$$ is equivalent to $$x>0$$ and $$x+1>0$$ or
$$x<0$$ and $$x+1>0$$

Comment: Don't you mean, in your first condition, that $x>0$ and $x+1<0$?

Comment: Yes, this case is impossible, we get only $$x<0$$ and $$x>-1$$ this means $$-1<x<0$$